# you should always use reasonable case -- what do they mean by "case" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This text is part of the copyright page from the book [*IP Addressing and Subnetting, Including IPv6 by Syngress (2000)*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1928994016):

> You should always **use reasonable case**, including backup and other appropriate precautions, when working with computers, networks, data, and files.

I checked all possible meanings typically found in a garden-variety English dictionary, but I don't think I saw one fitting the way it is used in this legal sentence. Any idea as to what it really means here?

Comment: I think that "reasonable care" was intended.

Comment: Voting to close because the question is based on a typographical error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a misprint.  As Mick suggests in his comment, "reasonable care" is more likely, meaning "use good judgement" and "take all reasonable steps (to protect your data), including ..."